# properly loading datetime in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm loading a tsv file with a datetime column and long column with:

```
A = LOAD 'tweets-clean.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (date:datetime, userid:long);
DUMP A;
```

An example line of input:

```
Tue Feb 11 05:02:10 +0000 2014  205291417
```

that line of output:

```
, 205291417
```

How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'd want to load date as a chararray (date:chararray) and then can convert it to to a datetime using `FOREACH GENERATE` along with the [`ToDate`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.16.0/func.html#to-date) Pig built-in function.

The format string is based on the [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
A = LOAD 'tweets-clean.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (date:chararray, userid:long);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE ToDate(date, '<some format string>') AS date, userid;
DUMP B;
```

Comment: @kskp Please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Comments are for clarification on the existing answer

Comment: Sorry. Will do it.