# Convert 6 digit date to 8 digit

Tags: datetime, apache-pig, cloudera

I have a `|` delimited file, which has values like `150330`, which represents date. To standardize, I need to convert this values as `2015-03-30`. I need to do it in Pig, due to few more conversions.

Tried `ToDate` & `DateTime` functions, without any luck.

Any suggestion?

Comment: this one helped.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052578/properly-loading-datetime-in-pig

Comment: For a 6 digit date notation, how can we determine year ? In the example : 150320 might be 1915-03-20 or even 2015-03-20?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to convert "150330" into "2015-03-30", this is not a date problem but rather String manipulation

1. use `SUBSTRING` to get 15, 03, 30
2. use `CONCAT` to join all the substring.

However, as said @murali-rao, you have to know if your dealing with 19xx or 20xx dates.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pig function in following way

```
B = foreach A GENERATE SUBSTRING(ToString(ToDate('150330','yyMMdd')),0,10);
```

output is 
    (2015-03-30)